What type of interest rate data can the Euler-M discretization of the Vasicek interest rate be used to model?
I'm looking at analysing the Vasicek model via its EM discretization. I know the model represents instantaneous short rates but would it be valid to take US tbills (3 month) historical daily rates as the data in this situation? Or is there any other suggestions for more appropriate data to use. For context I'm implementing a unique estimation of the Vasicek parameter distributions and want a valid dataset for the Vasicek to model.
